# D3.js "end" transition callback is not being fired when switch to other browser tab

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

As in the title. Everything works fine when the window is active. When switches to another browser tab callback is not being fired. 
Is this normal behavior in transition in D3.js or am  I doing something wrong?

```
gs = svg.selectAll('g').data(data);
gs.each(function(d,i){
            d3.select(this).select('rect')
            .transition().delay(i*100).duration(2).attr({
                width:width,
                height :height,
                x:-width/2,
                y:-height/2,
                rx:width,
                ry:height
            }).style('opacity', .1)
            .each('end',function(d){
                console.log('End of transition '+i);
            })
        });
```

For the purposes of this post, I've simplified this example. It is too long to put it here. However, the version that I put above is the shortest and simplest example that does not work. It is indeed dependent on the browser, it's not working on this (Chromium 28.0.1500.71 Ubuntu 12.04). Works on the other (Firefiox 20.0).
I will put all the code for this example. There is also no errors in the console.

```
scope.data = [
{
    name:' Name1',
    ratio:0,
    pts:29
},
{
    name:'Name2',
    ratio:7,
    votes:3
},
{
    name:'Name3',
    ratio:8,
    votes:19
}];
...
var svg = d3.select(elem[0]),width=80,height=80,data = scope.data,gs;
 angular.forEach(data,function(v,i){
            svg.append("g").attr('transform',function(){
                return "translate("+(Math.random()*scope.width)+','+(Math.random()*scope.height)+") rotate(0)";
            }).append('rect');
        })
gs = svg.selectAll('g').data(data);
gs.each(function(d,i){
            d3.select(this).select('rect')
            .transition().delay(i*100).duration(2).attr({
                width:width,
                height :height,
                x:-width/2,
                y:-height/2,
                rx:width,
                ry:height
            }).style('opacity', .1)
            .each('end',function(d){
                console.log('End of transition '+i);
            })
        });
```

Comment: Hmm, sounds like it should be fired. Could you provide a complete example please? Also, what browser are you using and did you verify that the transition completes and does not simply stop in the middle?

Comment: Adding to @LarsKotthoff's questions: most modern browsers won't redraw the transition while you're on another tab (the transition functions won't get called until the browser is ready to repaint the screen).  However, as soon as you switch back to the first tab the transition should complete.  (Also, if you want to print `i` in the each function, you'll need to declare it as a parameter.)